In Search of best sorting algorithm for continues numbers
I am about to sort thousands of numbers with the Java code, what's best way?
What's the best sorting algorithm which will work efficiently with continuous numbers?
I tried simple selection sort and quick sort, but the time complexity for Selection sort is O(n2), and O(n*log(n)) for quick sort.
I am looking for pretty good algorithm which will sort my data efficiently.

If the numbers are compact: radix sort --- "I am about to sort thousands of numbers" - I doubt you will see a significant difference between quicksort and radix sort at this scale.

one possible definition of "best" is "with least development/usage effort" ==> use Arrays.sort() or Collections.sort()

Trying to invent your own sort is a bad sign.  Use the built in ones.

Looking at the standard java sort, which sources you can exploit, you'll see Arrays.sort and Collections.sort. The Arrays.sort is considerable faster due to the reordering possible in arrays.
Arrays.sort does internally "DualPivotQuicksort" but that is just a name for trying to find an optimal sort out of several algorithms. One such sort algorithm is for already (nearly) sorted arrays.
This means that it is probably best to use the standard Arrays.sort in production software. In special cases like sets (think of BitSet) other solutions become interesting.

Quick sort usually performs better than other alghoritms (it also does not have any extra memory requirements and it has small hidden constant).
There is no better sorting alghoritm than n*log(n), if you find one, you can go and get your Nobel price straight away :)

"There is no better sorting alghoritm than n*log(n)" - you forgot the "based on key comparison". With certain restrictions, there are faster sorting algorithms, e.g. raidx sort (wikipedia.org).

We are not talking about certain restrictions, we are talking about any input. Radix sort is usable in some special scenarious, but it also reach n*log n if the input is not ideal.

I would suggest you to have a look at Sorting.java
It sorts data faster than ever, time complexity for this algorithm will be 2N which is best at till now.
NOTE:

This code will work for full numbers and continuous numbers only,
This is best way to sort when you have continuous numbers only.
It may be BAD when you have huge difference in numbers.

I also appreciate any suggestions on this repo.

Include the code in your question.  If that github project changes or disappears, your answer, as it is currently written, will be useless to future readers.

One suggestion: try { ... } catch (Exception e) { throw e; } is basically doing nothing (and StackOverflow is not the site for code review - try  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)
